# JavaScript Arguments Object returning unexpected output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that is supposed to check whether or not arguments passed to the function are undefined, and if any one of them is, then return false. I'm using `node.js`.

The issue I'm having is that logging the `arguments` object to the console is returning an unexpected output.

Here is my arrow function:

```
var checkYargsExist = () => {
    //console.log(arguments);
    for (x in arguments) {  
        if (arguments[x] === undefined) {
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

Suppose: 
var alpha = "apple";
var beta = "banana";

If I call the function as so: `checkYargsExist(alpha, beta)`, I expect `console.log()` to spit out `[alpha, beta]`, and compare `"apple" === undefined`, `"banana" === undefined` but my terminal is spitting out something like this:

```
{ '0': {},
  '1': 
   { [Function: require]
     resolve: [Function: resolve],
     main: 
      Module {
        id: '.',
        exports: {},
        parent: null,
        filename: '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/app.js',
        loaded: false,
        children: [Object],
        paths: [Object] },
     extensions: { '.js': [Function], '.json': [Function], '.node': [Function] },
     cache: 
      { '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/app.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/yargs/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/lodash.assign/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/yargs/lib/completion.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/yargs-parser/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/camelcase/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/yargs-parser/lib/tokenize-arg-string.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/yargs/lib/usage.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/cliui/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/string-width/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/code-point-at/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/number-is-nan/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/wrap-ansi/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/decamelize/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/window-size/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/yargs/lib/obj-filter.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/set-blocking/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/yargs/lib/validation.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/y18n/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/read-pkg-up/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/find-up/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/path-exists/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/pinkie-promise/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/read-pkg/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/load-json-file/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/graceful-fs/legacy-streams.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/strip-bom/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/is-utf8/is-utf8.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/parse-json/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/error-ex/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/is-arrayish/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/parse-json/vendor/parse.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/parse-json/vendor/unicode.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/pify/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/semver/semver.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/parser.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/spdx-correct/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/spdx-license-ids/spdx-license-ids.json': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/hosted-git-info/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/hosted-git-info/git-host-info.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/hosted-git-info/git-host.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/is-builtin-module/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/builtin-modules/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/extract_description.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/typos.json': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/make_warning.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/warning_messages.json': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/path-type/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/pkg-conf/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/object-assign/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/symbol/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/require-main-filename/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/notes.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/os-locale/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/lcid/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/invert-kv/index.js': [Object],
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules/lcid/lcid.json': [Object] } },
  '2': 
   Module {
     id: '.',
     exports: {},
     parent: null,
     filename: '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/app.js',
     loaded: false,
     children: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     paths: 
      [ '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/node_modules',
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/node_modules',
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/node_modules',
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/node_modules',
        '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/node_modules',
        '/Users/raigovind93/node_modules',
        '/Users/node_modules',
        '/node_modules' ] },
  '3': '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app/app.js',
  '4': '/Users/raigovind93/Dropbox/Localhost/Coding/Node/notes-node-app' }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `The return statement stops the execution of a function and returns a value from that function.` this means that you cannot put any code below the return statement.

Comment: You haven't passed arguments in arrow function so you have declared global @GovindRai ?

Comment: What is purpose of `return false`?

Comment: @YogeshPatel — The code is missing the bit where the function is called, so you can't tell that.

Comment: @Quentin i am asking him. I have put question mark at the end of sentence sir.

Comment: @guest271314 I use the boolean value later in my code in an `if` block. I realized the statement never returned `true` if it wasn't `false` so I've added `return true` in as well, thanks to your comment :D

Comment: @YogeshPatel I didn't put in arguments because the function can take any number of `arguments`, hence the use of the arguments object, but I also realize I need to write in an edge case where I can throw an error if the user calls `checkYargsExist()` without any arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and **does not bind** its own this, **arguments**, super, or new.target.

You are examining the `arguments` of the scope the function was created in.

If you want to use the `arguments` of the function, then don't create it using an arrow function. Stick to a regular function declaration or function expression instead.

Comment: Ah, I never knew that! Just following a course where the instructor is really pushing arrow functions.. definitely have look into pros/cons! Thanks!